# Depends libntfs10 error while installing testdisk

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk

I want to install testdisk to ubuntu 10.04 LTS but i'm getting an error. Any help? Here is the output:

```
# sudo apt-get install testdisk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  testdisk: Depends: libntfs10 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

---

I also tried:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/40386584/libntfs10_2.0.0-1ubuntu4_i386.deb; sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

And i get this error:

```
dpkg: error processing libntfs10_2.0.0-1ubuntu4_i386.deb (--install):
 package architecture (i386) does not match system (amd64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libntfs10_2.0.0-1ubuntu4_i386.deb
```

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get install libntfs10` give you? **Edit** your question to add the above details please.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libntfs10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libntfs10 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package libntfs10 has no installation candidate

Comment: As I stated above, ***edit*** your question. Please do **not** post comments giving additional details. // Try this: `cd /tmp; sudo mkdir temp; cd temp; sudo wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/40386584/libntfs10_2.0.0-1ubuntu4_i386.deb; sudo dpkg -i *.deb; cd`. Now, retry to install testdisk: `sudo apt-get install testdisk`.

Comment: Oh, you're on a 64-bit machine :) Here you go! `cd /tmp; sudo mkdir temp2; cd temp2; sudo wget  http://ubuntu.mirror.iweb.ca//pool/main/l/linux-ntfs/libntfs10_2.0.0-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb; sudo dpkg -i *.deb; cd`. Now, retry to install testdisk: `sudo apt-get install testdisk`.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll add an answer; if you could just accept it, it'll prevent the question from showing up an *Unanswered*. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following commands:

```
cd /tmp
sudo mkdir download
cd download
sudo wget http://ubuntu.mirror.iweb.ca//pool/main/l/linux-ntfs/libntfs10_2.0.0-1ubuntu4_am‌​d64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
cd
```

Now, retry to install `testdisk`:

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

> **Note:** The above instructions are for a 64-bit machine.